# Use CL_ABAP_CORRESPONDING to map fields on diffrent levels in a structure

Tags: data-structures, mapping, abap

I have two nested structure and I want to map the field at runtime according to some rules. It can append that the field of the dest structure and the source structure are on different level of the nested structures.

(The structures have different types)

For example I want to map:

```
struct1-a1 = struct2-bsub1-s1_b1.
struct1-asub1-s1_a1 = struct2-b1.
```

```
    DATA:
      BEGIN OF struct1,
        a1 TYPE string VALUE 'a1',
        a2 TYPE string VALUE 'a2',
        a3 TYPE string VALUE 'a3',
        a4 TYPE string VALUE 'a4',
        a5 TYPE string VALUE 'a5',
        BEGIN OF asub1,
          s1_a1 TYPE string VALUE 's1_a1',
          s1_a2 TYPE string VALUE 's1_a2',
          s1_a3 TYPE string VALUE 's1_a3',
        END OF asub1,
      END OF struct1,

      BEGIN OF struct2,
        b1 TYPE string VALUE 'b1',
        b2 TYPE string VALUE 'b2',
        b3 TYPE string VALUE 'b3',
        a4 TYPE string VALUE 'b4',
        a5 TYPE string VALUE 'b5',
        BEGIN OF bsub1,
          s1_b1 TYPE string VALUE 's1_b1',
          s1_b2 TYPE string VALUE 's1_b2',
          s1_b3 TYPE string VALUE 's1_b3',
        END OF bsub1,
      END OF struct2.
```

I found this cool class to build mapping for fields, but it has only one level parameter.

My question is can I use [the class CL_ABAP_CORRESPONDING](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/index.htm?file=abencl_abap_corresponding.htm) to map fields on different levels and how can I do it.

Comment: Is the component structure of your two nested structures known statically, i.e. fixed at designtime, or does is it dynamic, i.e. varies at runtime? If it is static, you should also investigate the [`CORRESPONDING` operator](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/index.htm?file=abencl_abap_corresponding.htm).

Comment: The ABAP documentation provides many examples, especially this one for "[nested structures](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/index.htm?file=abencl_abap_corr_struc_abexa.htm)". It exists since 7.50.

Comment: Yes it's known, but I can't statically write it in my code because the field assignment is dependen on user customizing. So the mapping can change at anytime.

Comment: @SandraRossi The nested strucutres exmaple doesn't have a use case for fields on diffrent levels as far as I can see. Thats my problem.

Comment: I edited the question to add structures so that people can propose solutions based on them (with `CL_ABAP_CORRESPONDING` or other better solutions)

Comment: Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't, mapped structures must be on the same level. Excerpt from the class docu:

> Notes
>
> Components can only be mapped to each other if they are on the same level. Components in a substructure cannot be assigned to the components at higher levels, nor higher level components to components in a substructure.

You must split into several executions:

```
cl_abap_corresponding=>create(
      source            = struct2-bsub1
      destination       = struct1
      mapping           = VALUE cl_abap_corresponding=>mapping_table(
                          ( level = 0 kind = 1 srcname = 's1_b1' dstname = 'a1' ) )
      )->execute( EXPORTING source      = struct2-bsub1
                  CHANGING  destination = struct1 ).

cl_abap_corresponding=>create(
      source            = struct2
      destination       = struct1-asub1
      mapping           = VALUE cl_abap_corresponding=>mapping_table(
                          ( level = 0 kind = 1 srcname = 's1_a1' dstname = 'b1' ) )
      )->execute( EXPORTING source      = struct2
                  CHANGING  destination = struct1-asub1 ).
```

EDIT: although the documentation seems straight forward, I found out that the component selector may be used inside the `SRCNAME` component, to refer to a component from a nested structure, e.g. the first execution above is equivalent to this code (the differences are in `source = struct2` and in `srcname = 'bsub1-s1_b1'`):

```
cl_abap_corresponding=>create(
      source            = struct2
      destination       = struct1
      mapping           = VALUE cl_abap_corresponding=>mapping_table(
                          ( level = 0 kind = 1 srcname = 'bsub1-s1_b1' dstname = 'a1' ) )
      )->execute( EXPORTING source      = struct2
                  CHANGING  destination = struct1 ).
```

What seems to be still **impossible** is to use the component selector in the `DSTNAME` component, e.g. the second execution cannot indicate `destination = struct1` and `dstname = 'asub1-b1'`, an exception would occur.